# Limiting distribution of $\frac{X_1+···+X_n}{\sqrt{X_1^2+···+X_n^2}}$ for $(X_i)$ i.i.d. logistic with mean $0$ and variance $2$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

> $X_1$, $X_2$, . . . are iid logistic random variables with mean $0$
>   and variance $2$, and
>   $$T_n=\frac{X_1+···+X_n}{\sqrt{X_1^2+···+X_n^2}}$$Consider the
>   sequence $T_1$, $T_2$, . . . and give the pmf or pdf of the limiting
>   distribution.

I have that for a logistic random variable $X$

$$\mathsf{Var}(X)=\frac{\pi^2\beta^2}{3}$$

and so $\beta=\sqrt{\frac{6}{\pi^2}}$ giving that $X\sim Logistic\left(\mu=0,\beta=\sqrt{\frac{6}{\pi^2}}\right)$ with pdf

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{6}{\pi^2}}}\frac{e^\frac{-x}{\sqrt{\frac{6}{\pi^2}}}}{\left(1+e^\frac{-x}{\sqrt{\frac{6}{\pi^2}}}\right)^2}, -\infty\lt x\lt\infty$$

I think it may be useful to note that by symmetry of $X$ around $0$, we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=0$$

My intuition tells me this will converge to a degenerate random variable for which $$P(T=0)=1$$

but I'm not sure how to go about formalizing this.

Comment: I don't see why $\lim\sum X_i=0$.  You have $\lim n^{-1/2}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\sim N(0,2)$ and so $\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i>\epsilon)\to\frac12$ as $n\to\infty$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $T_n=U_n/\sqrt{V_n}$ where $$U_n=\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$$ hence, by the classical CLT, $U_n$ converges in distribution to a normal distribution $N(0,2)$, and $$V_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k^2$$ hence, by the classical law of large numbers, $V_n\to2$ almost surely, to deduce that $T_n$ converges in distribution to the standard normal distribution.

Comment: ((Sorry but you seem to be repeating some of the misconceptions which were already carefully debunked à propos your previous question: no, $P(T_n=0)$ is not $1$, in fact $P(T_n=0)=0$ for every $n$.))

Comment: Thank you @Did. I think (hopefully) I have it right now. I have edited my post.

Comment: Remy: Post as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing @Did's helpful comment:

We have that by CLT $$\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\sum{X_n}}{n}-0\right)\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}\mathsf{N}(0,2)$$

Hence

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(X_1+...+X_n)
\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}\mathsf{N}(0,2)$$

We also have that

$$\mathsf E(X^2)=\mathsf{Var}(X)+\mathsf E(X)^2=2$$

Thus by the law of large numbers

$$V_n\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow}2$$

and hence

$$\sqrt{V_n}\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow}\sqrt{2}$$

By Skutsky's Theorem we get that

$$\frac{U_n}{\sqrt{V_n}}\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\mathsf N(0,2)=\mathsf N(0,1)$$

Thus the pdf of the limiting distribution is

$$f_T(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathsf{exp}\left(-\frac{t^2}{2}\right), -\infty\lt t\lt\infty$$